# NX @nrwl/node generator error "Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/code-frames"

Tags: node.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am attempting to generate a new node project using `@nrwl/node` and when I use the generator I am met with the error

```
 NX   Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/code-frames'
```

inhibiting me from running the generator.

my nx version is 15.2.1
my @nrwl/node version is 15.9.2
and my node version is 16.17.0

Ive attempted to reinstall the packages multiple times to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nx` and `@nrwl/node` ***must*** be at the same version. You should see an error if you run `nx workspace-lint` (prior to its deprecation), or during `nx report` on newer versions.

`nx migrate latest` would get things synced back up.

Answer (score 2):

**Run** `nx report`

You will get results like the following:

> NX   Some packages have misaligned versions!    These packages should
> match your installed version of Nx.
>
> - @nrwl/angular@15.9.3
> - @nrwl/cypress@15.6.3
> - @nrwl/js@15.6.3
> - @nrwl/react@15.9.3
> - @nrwl/webpack@15.6.3    You should be able to fix this by running `nx migrate 15.9.3`

**Running** `nx migrate 15.9.3`

**Then** `Yarn` or `NPM i`

**The conflict will be solved**

Answer (score 0):

For me I had

`@nrwl/webpack": "^15.0.13"`
while all my other packages were without the **^** so like
`"@nrwl/webpack": "15.0.13"`

Which the migrations thing did identify but didn't fix, so anyway check that your versions match not only in number but also in versioning scheme or whatever this is called

so basically i just had to remove the ^ from my webpack dep